# Winston logger stops logging when PC is in sleep mode

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I have to run my node server application in background using windows service. There are some periodic operations happening using rest api. Node Server uses winston logger to log the api request/response in external file. Logs are created based on 10 Mb file size.

I am using the following:

node v10.15.3
express v4.16.4
winston v3.2.1

My PC has sleep time of 15 minutes. When PC goes in sleep mode, winston logger stops logging. Also when sleep mode is revoked, no new log files are generated.

Can anyone help me solving this issue?

Comment: @dwjohnston :D I hope you had understood the problem